# How to use AWS Cognito Userpool token to log into AWS Api gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have created an API gateway endpoint with a lambda function at the backend.
Then I created a cognito userpool with one account and configured the cognito userpool as authorizer in API Gateway. I could see that the API was unauthorized.

Then I created a small web page with AWS Cognito Javascript SDK to log into the userpool and get an access token. I was able to do that successfully. Here is the code.

```js
    var authenticationData = {
        Username : 'username',
        Password : 'test123',
    };
    var authenticationDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);
    var poolData = {
        UserPoolId : 'ap-southeast-2_12312', // Your user pool id here
        ClientId : '434324324' // Your client id here
    };
    var userPool = new CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var userData = {
        Username : 'username',
        Pool : userPool
    };

    var self = this;
    var cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            var tok = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
            console.log('access token + ' + tok);
            self.setState({ token: tok });
            //POTENTIAL: Region needs to be set if not already set previously elsewhere.
            // AWS.config.region = '<region>';

            // AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
            //     IdentityPoolId : '...', // your identity pool id here
            //     Logins : {
            //         // Change the key below according to the specific region your user pool is in.
            //         'cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<YOUR_USER_POOL_ID>' : tok
            //     }
            // });

            // Instantiate aws sdk service objects now that the credentials have been updated.
            // example: var s3 = new AWS.S3();
        },

        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        },
    });
```

This code works and gives me a JWT Token. However that token does not authorizes me into the API. I am passing the token in the Authorization header without the Bearer keyword but I still cannot access the API. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to debug more easily using the 'Test' feature for authorizers in the API Gateway console. You can paste the valid JWT token there and run a test on the authorizer; if there are any issues you should see them in the Logs output.

Comment: There is a test page for Authorizer as well. My JWT Token is not working there as well.

Comment: The Test inside the API console is working with and without the JWT Token.

Comment: Yep I'm talking about the test page for Authorizer. If the token isn't working there then you should be able to debug the problem using the Logs output. The tokens do expire so make sure you are testing with a fresh token. The token must be issued from a User Pool matching a 'providerARN' you set on the authorizer.